# How Do I Multiply Two ng-module Values in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How to multiply to values in table , in `table` `Payment value` as with in `comma`, `commission` value  as  in without `comma` so how to multiply these two values.....[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zFrSqDWvE5pr3jgKO91?p=preview)   **For Example** :-1. Transaction:-  payment value is `1,925.10` and commission value is `3` how to multiply comma value and without comma value example:- `1,925.10*3  = 5775.3`...

**For Example** :-2. Trasaction:-  payment value is `1,925.10` and commission value is `5` how to multiply comma value and without comma value example:- `1,925.10*5  = 9625.5`...

**My Html:-**

```
<td >{{mani.payment }}</td>

    <td >{{mani.commission}}</td>

        <td >{{(mani.payment) * (mani.commission)}}</td>
```

**My Data:-**

```
  {
  "_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
  "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
  "remarks": "-",
  "commission": "3",
  "status": "pending",
  "amt": "4000",
  "cheque_currency": "Rs",
  "cheque_value": "300",
  "payment": "1,925.10",
  "debitnote_no_payment": "3",
  "supplier_name": "karikalan",
  "buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
},

{
"_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
"user": {
  "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
  "displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
"remarks": "-",
 "commission": "5",
"status": "pending",
"amt": "2000",
"cheque_currency": "Rs",
"cheque_value": "300",
"payment": "1,925.10",
"debitnote_no_payment": "3",
"supplier_name": "karikalan",
"buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
},
```

I have created Plunker for reference:- [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zFrSqDWvE5pr3jgKO91?p=preview)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/29507259/1929187

Comment: Please look at my plunker  I'M asked how to multiply comma value and without comma value  in table....this is not related question, if u knw the solution please update plunker as well to the solution thanks, please help us...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your plunker, simply replacing this line:

```
<td>{{(mani.payment) * (mani.commission)}}</td>
```

With this other:

```
<td>{{(mani.payment.replace(',','')) * (mani.commission.replace(',',''))}}</td>
```

Solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

you really should change '1,925.10' to 1925.10 when you respond the request.

1925.10 is the real value, however '1,925.10' is one of its form.

or [Make parseFloat convert variables with commas into numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209784/make-parsefloat-convert-variables-with-commas-into-numbers)

```
function parseFloatIgnoreCommas(number) {
    var numberNoCommas = number.replace(/,/g, '');
    return parseFloat(numberNoCommas);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, i got answer like with comma 1,925.10 only, so can you please update plunker as well to know the solution please help us....

Comment: or just convert it to a valid number

Answer (score 0):

The number you pass for multiplication isn't a number actualy, It is a string Check your plunkr I have updated it..Or Please Pass it as a number in your JSON.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3zFrSqDWvE5pr3jgKO91?p=preview

```
 <tr ng-repeat="mani in resultValue=(sryarndebitnote)"> 
        <td >{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td >{{mani.amt}}</td>
            <td >{{mani.payment }}</td>
            <td >{{mani.commission}}</td>
             <td >{{(mani.payment) * (mani.commission)}}</td>

           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>sum</td>
             <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'amt'}}</td>
             <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'payment'}}</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
```

Or

```
 $scope.sryarndebitnote = [
{
  "_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
  "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
  "remarks": "-",
  "commission": "3",
  "status": "pending",
  "amt": "4000",
  "cheque_currency": "Rs",
  "cheque_value": "300",
  "payment": 1925.10, // Change to number
  "debitnote_no_payment": "3",
  "supplier_name": "karikalan",
  "buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
},
{
"_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
"user": {
  "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
  "displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
"remarks": "-",
 "commission": "5",
"status": "pending",
"amt": "2000",
"cheque_currency": "Rs",
"cheque_value": "300",
"payment": 1925.10,
"debitnote_no_payment": "3",
"supplier_name": "karikalan",
"buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
}
   ];
```